# Proof of an alternative form of Taylor's approximation

Tags: taylor-expansion

Theorem: Suppose that $\space f:R^{n} \rightarrow R$ is a continuously differentiable and that $p \in R^n$ . Then we have that
$$f (x + p) = f (x) + ∇ f (x + t p)^T p$$
where $t \in (0,1)$.

And if $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, we have that
$$f (x + p)  = f (x) + ∇ f (x)^T p + \frac{1}{2}p^T ∇^2 f (x + t p) p$$
where $t \in (0,1)$.

I found this statement in a book without its proof. I tried searching several books of calculus to find it but couldn't find a simple proof of this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would do it. Define $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ by
$$
g(t)=f(x+tp).
$$
Since $f$ is differentiable, so is $g$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $t\in(0,1)$ with 
$$
f(x+p)-f(x)=g(1)-g(0)=g'(t). 
$$
By the Chain Rule, 
$$
g'(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x+tp)\,p_j=\nabla f(x+tp)^Tp.
$$
Using the Chain Rule again,
\begin{align}
g''(t)&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x+tp)\,p_j\right)\,p_k
=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_k\partial x_j}
(x+tp)\,p_j\,p_k\\ \ \\
&=p^TH(x+tp)\,p,
\end{align}
where $H$ is the [Hessian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $f$. The notation $\nabla^2$, while bad and usually used for something else, is more or less coherent since in a sense the Hessian is the gradient of the gradient.

Comment: Explanation is simple and convincing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any hint for the second part?

Comment: It looks like $$g (1)=g (0)+g'(0)+\frac12\,g''(t). $$

Comment: How did you reach that statement?

Comment: It's the first degree Taylor polynomial, plus the error term.

Comment: If possible please mention the proof of the second statement also in the answer that will make it complete. I am not able to derive it on my own.

Comment: It's a completely straightforward calculation. I have edited it into the answer.